# Find a key in a hash whose value is not the given value

Tags: ruby, hash

How can I find the first key in a hash that has a value which isn't equal to a given value? Given the following hash and the value `100`,

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 100, "c" => 800, "d" => 500 }
```

I want to find `"c" => 800`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. `"c" => 800` is not a Ruby object. We can guess that you wanted either the key `"c"` or the value `800`, or perhaps a hash `{"c" => 800}`, but which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
no_match_value = 100

h.find { |k,v| v != no_match_value }.first #=> "c"
```

It's unusual to look for a key or value that is in a particular location in a hash, but (since Ruby v1.9) you can do that. The ordering is determined by key-insertion order. Until v1.9 there was no concept of hash keys being ordered, just as elements of a set are not ordered. Some Rubiests consider key ordering to be heresy; others, myself included, have found good uses for it.

Comment: @Anthony, I presume you mean that as alternative to tacking on `.first`. (It's no more efficient, of course, as `find` stops as soon as it the block evaluates `true`). You could also write `h.each_key.find { |k| h[k] != no_match_value }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select`

```
Hash[*h.select {|_, v| v != 100}.first]
#=> {"c"=>800}
```

It returns an empty hash `{}` if there is no match.

Without the `Hash[]` part, it returns an array with key and value.

Comment: Add with it `.first` to take the first one

Comment: `detect`/`find` would be a better fit :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, why better?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, actually first or nil or zero if not found.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, yes, zero or something else as a default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 100, "c" => 800, "d" => 500 }
h.reject!{|k,v| v == 100}

# h = {"c"=>800, "d"=>500}
```

The resulting hash will have all key/value pairs where the value isn't 100.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the key, below code will work:

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 100, "c" => 800, "d" => 500 }
result = h.detect{ |k,v| v != 100 }.first
```